# phph shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell

The following code below works and reboots the system once it receives the reboot command, however for some strange reason it does not execute this shell command `sudo i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0xa5` , any help please.

```
<?php

  function sys_cmd($cmd) {
    if(strncmp($cmd, "reboot", strlen("reboot")) == 0) 
    {
      shell_exec('sudo shutdown -r now');
    } 
    else if(strncmp($cmd, "lighton", strlen("lighton")) == 0) 
    {
      shell_exec('sudo i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0xa5');
    }
    else if(strncmp($cmd, "lightoff", strlen("lightoff")) == 0) 
    {
      shell_exec('sudo i2cset -y 1 0x70 0x00 0x00');
    }
    else {
      // unknown
    }
  }


  if(isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $cmd=$_GET['cmd'];
    sys_cmd($cmd);
  }

?>
```

Comment: to my knowledge `sudo` requires that you enter a password

Comment: sudo shutdown command work perfectly

Comment: helpfull ideas: Check error.log and /var/messages on your server, those should hold enough information for you to understand what's what. But! I might know why this isn't working, check if "i2cset" is a "sudoable" command for "no password sudo" (google it up, forgot the link)

Comment: do BOTH of the i2cset calls fail? There'd be absolutely NO reason for `lightoff` to work while `lighton` fails at the PHP level, unless you're passing in the wrong hex strings... but that'd be your problem, not php's.

Comment: both light on and light off do not work, the reboot however works. the i2cset required sudo and so does the reboot!!

Comment: this command does not work too 
./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface/RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh start